# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my create trigger syntax?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am experimenting with triggers for the first time.

When I try to create a trigger using the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_foldersPrivate BEFORE DELETE ON foldersPrivate
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DELETE FROM programs WHERE folderType = '0' AND folderID = OLD.ID; 
END;
```

I receive the following error:

```
`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`
```

(mysql 5.1.37)

If I get rid fo the delete statement the create trigger statement works fine.  So I am assuming it must have something to do with that.  But for the life of me I'm not sure what...

Answer (score 1):

You should change the delimiters.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER t_foldersPrivate BEFORE DELETE ON foldersPrivate
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DELETE FROM programs WHERE folderType = '0' AND folderID = OLD.ID; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Also, you should check the delete query separately. Is it working?

Comment: Yes, the delete statement works fine separately.

I tried using the above code, however it has the effect of crashing phpMyAdmin.  The whole thing seized up until I restarted mysql...

Comment: I thing it's wrong to call "OLD.ID" in an "before" event. Thnik about it.

Try doing this:

DELETE FROM programs WHERE folderType = '0' AND folderID = ID;